# Recommendation books on graduate level vector analysis and field analysis with application of electrodynamics?

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, vector-fields

I am currently a physics and mathematics double major graduate student. Looking for a text book and problem sets on the topic of vector field analysis, would be best if the book is advanced and problems is difficult. Also with application to classical electrodynamics/